# Does the solvability of an equation $I=MV+NC$ for $V$ depend on $Ker(C)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

In a recently read paper I came across the statement that for matrices $M\in\Re^{n\times{n}_{1}}$, $N\in\Re^{n\times{s}_1}$, $C\in\Re^{s_1\times{n}}$, the equation
\begin{equation}
I=MV+NC   \tag{1} 
\end{equation}
has a solution for $V\in\Re^{n_1\times{n}}$ if the number of linear independent rows of $V$ must be at least equal to the dimension of $Ker(C)$. To show that the claim is true, lets take a vector $x\in{Ker(C)}$, then the above equation reduces to 
\begin{equation}
x=MVx=M\begin{bmatrix}V_{1}x\\V_{2}x\\\vdots\\V_{n_1}x\end{bmatrix} \tag{2} 
\end{equation}
where $V_{i}$ is the $i^{th}$ row of $V$. Since $Ker(C)\neq\{0\}$ and thus $x\neq{0}$ for which equation 2 holds if $MV=I$ or $rank(MV)\leq{n}$. But I do not see the way forward. Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This isn't necessarily the case if $M = 0$ or $N = 0$.  What information are we given?  Do we know that $M$ and $N$ have full rank?

Comment: It is clear that the condition is necessary though, since
$$
\operatorname{rank}(MV + NC) \leq \operatorname{rank}(V) + \operatorname{rank}(C)
$$

Comment: Matrices $M$ and $N$ are non-zero but nothing is known for sure on the rank of $M$ and $N$. If these matrices are of full column rank, then your last comment holds.

Comment: My last comment holds whether or not $M$ and $N$ have full rank.  However, if we're not guaranteed that $M,N$ have full rank, then no condition on $C,V$ will guarantee solvability.